# Integral of the ratio of two exponential sums

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, summation, hyperbolic-functions

I am trying to find a lower bound on the following integral

\begin{align*}
\int_{y=-\infty}^{y=\infty} \frac{ (\sum_{n=[-N..N]/\{0\}}n e^{-\frac{(y-cn)^2}{2}})^2} {\sum_{n=[-N..N]/\{0\}} e^{-\frac{(y-cn)^2}{2}}}dy
\end{align*}

I have been trying to find the  upper and the lower bounds on the summations in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280703/how-to-compute-sum-n-1n-e-n-c2).

I have also look at the Jacobian-Theta functions but I wasn't able to find theta function that would match my cases.

Another approach is to look at hyperbolic functions 
\begin{align*}
&\int_{y=-\infty}^{y=\infty} \frac{ (\sum_{n=[-N..N]/\{0\}}n e^{-\frac{(y-cn)^2}{2}})^2} {\sum_{n=[-N..N]/\{0\}} e^{-\frac{(y-cn)^2}{2}}}dy\\
&=\int_{y=-\infty}^{y=\infty} \frac{ e^{-y^2/2}\left(\sum_{n=[1..N]}n e^{-\frac{c^2n^2}{2}} \sinh(ncy)\right)^2} {\sum_{n=[1..N]} e^{-\frac{c^2n^2}{2}} \cosh(ncy)}dy\\
\end{align*}

But how to compute or bound the hyperbolic sums? Again, I only require a lower bound on the above integral.

Should elliptic functions come into the play here, but I am not sure?
I feel like the sums inside of the integral were already looked at, so I would also be very grateful if you can point me to some references.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice you might offer.

**Please see a very nice  approach by @Dr. MV.   The point of starting a  bounty is to maybe show a tighter result.**

Comment: Have you looked at Cauchy-Schwartz?

Comment: But Cauch-Schwartz would be in the wrong direction. Remember I I want a lower bound on the integral. Right?

Comment: See if there is a way to rearrange things.

Comment: I provided a lower bound using Cauchy-Schwartz.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: I look at it all and back away very slowly

Comment: @ZelosMalum How so?

Comment: Because currently I am not comfortable with these so they look intimidating so I decieded to add a playful comment to make people smile :)

Comment: Thanks man. If there were  more people like you...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We seek a lower bound for the integral $I_N$ where

$$I_N=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{ (\sum_{1\le |n|\le N}n e^{-(y-cn)^2/2})^2} {\sum_{1\le |n|\le N} e^{-(y-cn)^2/2}}dy$$

Let the integrand be denoted by the square of the function $f_N$ such that

$$f_N^2(x)=\frac{ (\sum_{1\le |n|\le N}n e^{-(y-cn)^2/2})^2} {\sum_{1\le |n|\le N} e^{-(y-cn)^2/2}}$$

Also, let the denominator of $f_N^2$ be denoted by the square of the function $g$ such that

$$g_N^2(x)=\sum_{1\le |n|\le N} e^{-(y-cn)^2/2}$$

Applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

$$\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_N(x)g_N(x)dx\right)^2\le \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_N(x)^2dx\,\,\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g_N^2(x)dx$$

implies that

$$\begin{align}
I_N&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_N(x)^2 \, dx\\\\
&\ge \frac{\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_N(x)g_N(x)\,dx\right)^2}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty g_N^2(x)\,dx}\\\\
&=\frac{\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left|\sum_{1\le |n|\le N} n e^{-(y-cn)^2/2}\right|\,dx\right)^2}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sum_{1\le |n|\le N} e^{-(y-cn)^2/2}\,dx}\\\\
&=2\sqrt{\pi}\frac1 N \left(\sum_{n=1}^N n\operatorname{erf}(cn)\right)^2
\end{align}$$

Comment: This is an amazing proof. Thank you very much. How did you come up with this? Have you seen something like this before?

Comment: Thank you. The last part I can see.

Comment: Does this approach with Cauchy Schwartz lead to tight bounds or do you think there are better bounds?

Comment: I think there must be better bounds.  But don't forget the absolute value sign in the numerator.  Without it, the lower bound would be zero.  And we didn't need CS to know that.

Comment: Could you point me to another approach. That might result in better bound? If you want we can start a bounty on this question.

Comment: @ Dr. MV   I think Cauchy-Schwartz is not very tight in this case.

Comment: Have you carried out the integral of the numerator?

Comment: @ Dr. Mv Yes. I have it's basically $\frac{1}{2} N (N+1) \sqrt{2\pi} \erf{c/\sqrt{2}}$. Hey, I know I took the check mark. I still really like your answer. The reason I did it to grab more attention. If no one answers I will award the bounty to you.

Comment: @Boby I carried out the integrals and provided the final result in terms of the average of weighted error functions.  Let me know if this helps.

Comment: When I did it I got a factor $\sqrt{2\pi}$ in there

Comment: Observe, that  for $c>1$ the bound is independent of $c$. Since $\rm{erf}(cn) \approx 1$. But my feeling is that the integral depends heavily on $c$.

Comment: There's a really conspicuous difference between the result of n\text{erf}(cn) and that of n\operatorname{erf}(cn): $\displaystyle n\text{erf}(cn)$ versus $\displaystyle n\operatorname{erf}(cn)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for the edit.  I am out of town and working from a "smart phone."  Much appreciative of the help.