# Can summation $\sum_{n=[-N\ldots N]}n e^{-\frac{(y-cn)^2}{2}}$ be lower bouned by integration $\int_{-N}^Nx e^{-\frac{(y-cx)^2}{2}} dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation

I was wondering if the following summation 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=[-N \ldots N]}n e^{-\frac{(y-cn)^2}{2}}
\end{align*}
can be lower bounded by integral
$$
\int_{-N}^Nx e^{-\frac{(y-cx)^2}{2}} \, dx  
$$
where $y,c$ are fixed constants. This should some how be related to integral test but to use it I think I need that the function is non-negative and monotone decreasing.

The reason is that this integral is easy to compute and given by this expression $\frac{1}{c^2} \left(e^{- (cN-y)^2/2} -e^{-(cN+y)^2/2}+y \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left( {\rm erf} \left(\frac{cN-y}{\sqrt{2}} \right) +{\rm erf} \left(\frac{cNy}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \right)\right)$.

This question is related to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281053/integral-of-the-ratio-of-two-exponential-sums/1282087?noredirect=1#comment2609435_1282087).
I feel the above summation should be well know but I couldn't find any results.